# What happened to test-binder in Spring Cloud Stream / Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm failing to find any documentation on this, but what happened to the test-binder for Spring Cloud Stream / Spring Boot 3?

This use to work fine with 2021 bom imports, but now get this error: *Could not find spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4-test-binder.jar (org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:4.0.4).*

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.4")
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-test'
    testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream") {
        artifact {
            name = "spring-cloud-stream"
            extension = "jar"
            type = "test-jar"
            classifier = "test-binder"
        }
    }
}
```

The end goal was to write an integration test for a consumer using `@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)` and `InputDestination` and `OutputDestination`.

Is this even supported anymore? Are functional interfaces for Spring Cloud Stream in Spring Boot 3 being abandoned? If not, what is the new way to test with `@SpringBootTest`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is still supported. Helps to have a friend that can assist. Unfortunately, this is not documented well enough, but hopefully this helps others.

`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-test` has been discontinued and the `test-binder` jar has been moved to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder`.

**Update build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.4")
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder'
}
```

*Note the order of **test** and **binder** in the dependency name*

[GitHub Reference](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2598#issuecomment-1370227212)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean when you say not enough. What more can we add - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing???

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky apologies. I think it was personal confusion between the terminology of `test-binder` and `binder-test` in dependency names as well as frustration of SEO available to Google results. It was difficult to find and wasn't registering that those two were different dependencies. Also, for some reason Google returned results on deprecated dependencies removed from spring cloud stream, `StreamListener` and `EnableBinding`. Amazingly even [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-avro-confluent) has old user guides with recent dates.

Comment: Looking back at your link, that documentation is excellent! Getting to it must've been my main problem. Apologies again.

Comment: If you are able to improve SEO, here were a few of my first searches in Google:
"TestChannelBinderConfiguration spring boot 3", "spring boot 3 spring cloud stream test binder"